# Access a provider method from child @Input setter - Ionic2 / Angular2

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2

I'm trying to access a provider class from my components `@Input` method. However it seems like the provider is not available when the `@Input` method is called

Following is my code

```
#provider
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';


@Injectable()
export class MyProvider {

  constructor() {}

  sampleMethod(){
    return 'sample method';
  }
}

#component
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';
import {MyProvider} from '../../providers/my-provider/my-provider';
import { NavController} from 'ionic-angular';

@Component({
  selector: 'selected-options',
  templateUrl: 'build/components/selected-options/selected-options.html',
  inputs: ['node']
})
export class SelectedOptions {

  provider: MyProvider;

  @Input()
  set node(n: any){
     this.provider.sampleMethod();    
  }
}

#page (where I call the component) 
<selected-options [node]="node.Name"></selected-options>
```

So the issue is with the line

`this.provider.sampleMethod();`

The error I'm getting is `ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: TypeError: Cannot read property 'sampleMethod' of undefined`.

So I believe `provider: MyProvider;` is not loaded when the `@Input` method is called. But this works fine if I use it inside the constructor.
How can I access a provider method inside a `@Input` method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may sound confusing, but the error you're getting is because the provider is not being included in the constructor as a parameter (and because of that, your constructor is not creating an instance of the `MyProvider` class).

Please take a look at [this plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/bToHqJ?p=preview). Like you can se there, even though we use the `myProvider` instance in the `@Input` setter interceptor, the constructor already created the instance of the service, so you can call the `sampleMethod()` without problems.

```
import { Component, Input } from "@angular/core";
import { MyProvider } from './my-provider.ts';

@Component({
  templateUrl:"child.html",
  selector: 'child-selector',
  inputs: ['node']
})
export class ChildPage {

  private result: string;

  @Input()
  set node(node: string){
    // Because the provider instance is injected on the constructor, we can
    // call the sampleMethod() here
    node = node + ' from ChildPage';
    this.result = this.myProvider.sampleMethod(node);
  }

  // Injects an instance of the MyProvider class
  constructor(private myProvider: MyProvider) {

  }
}
```

So if you just add the `private myProvider: MyProvider` parameter in your constructor your code should work fine :)

Comment: Hey @sebaferreras, thanks again for the help, and the detailed explanation on the issue, that fixed my issue 

Comment: Np, that's what we're all here for :)

Answer (score 1):

To access your providers you have to tell the App about them. Regarding ionic2 on your app.ts when you are bootstrapping the app, add your provider

```
import {YourProviderWithInjectableDecorator} from 'somepath';

    ionicBootstrap(MyApp, [YourProviderWithInjectableDecorator])
```

on your class

```
Component({
  selector: 'selected-options',
  templateUrl: 'build/components/selected-options/selected-options.html',
  inputs: ['node']
})
export class SelectedOptions {

  constructor(private provider: MyProvider){}

  @Input()
  set node(n: any){
     this.provider.sampleMethod();    
  }
}
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Hey @Sudakatux, thanks for an answer, Yep I already have it `ionicBootstrap(MyApp, [MyProvider]);`

Comment: @injectable stuff are injected into the constructor() try creating the constructor method